# Windows email client with dark theme

Tags: windows, email, email-client, desktop-client, dark-theme

As someone who normally stares at Visual Studio and dark themed websites (thanks to [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)) all day, my eyes burn when I have to open up Outlook and its bleach white interface. To get around this, I've been using the web client with [this style](https://userstyles.org/styles/112094/dark-outlook), however I would really like to use a desktop client.

So can anyone recommend an email client that has a good dark theme (preferably compatible with Windows 8)?

Comment: Outlook has a dark theme on newer versions.  Not got it installed but as I recollect File -> Settings then there is a theme option in there.

Comment: I'm aware of the Light Gray and Dark Gray themes but unfortunately they just color the edges very lightly. I'm looking for something closer to Gmail's dark theme or, ideally, something that colors email bodies as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) has thousands of [themes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/complete-themes/), of which some are dark, and you can easily tweak the background and text colours yourself.

[image: Thunderbird]

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mail (not Outlook) has a nice dark theme.

[image]

Comment: Love the look of this, however this is only available for windows 10 correct?

Comment: I'm not sure - Windows 10 at least. Possibly 8.1

Answer (score 0):

While not perfect, eM Client has a free dark theme that you can find it [here](https://github.com/DeDu/Dark-Modern-Em-Client-Theme)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer some more? Maybe add a screenshot? Preferably a reader could vet your answer using only the data in the answer without having to follow any link.